# OrderBy after Select in linq generates the wrong SQL for DocumentDb?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a general, top level structure to the documents I'm storing in documentdb (using the cosmosdb emulator locally).  It looks something like this:

```
{
  DocType: "MyDocType",
  Document: { 
    // Some instance of MyDocType 
  }
}
```

In order to only deal with those specific document types, I'll select a subset of a certain doctype first, and then query whatever i'm looking for in the actual document.  For example, let's say MyDocType had a field named Order on it.  I would do something like:

```
var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery(_collectionUri);
query = query.Where(dw => dw.DocType == "MyDocType").Select(dw => dw.Document)
query = query.Where(d => d.Order >= 1).OrderBy(d => d.Order);
var results = query.ToList()                                         // <== No Results
```

If I look at the SQL that's generated, it looks something like this:

```
SELECT VALUE root["Document"] FROM root WHERE ((root["DocType"] = "MyDocType") AND (root["Document"]["Order"] >= 1)) ORDER BY root["Order"] ASC
```

So the Order By is being applied to the root, where Order doesn't exist, instead of to the Document where it does exist (and where the 2nd Where clause was correctly applied).

Am I applying ordering incorrectly here or is the DocumentDb linq driver being goofy?

Comment: Well, looks like this may be a bug in the linq implementation for documentdb:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/246